# Access variable in function of same object

Tags: javascript, json, function, typescript, object

```
{
    title: "This is title of item 1",
    desc: "This is description of 1",
    state: "inactive",
    toggleState: () => {
        console.log('title: ', title)
    }
}
```

This is an object in Typescript. I want to access title variable from this object in this object's function toggleState(). But I get error as

> [ts]: Cannot find name 'title'

Is it possible? if so, then how to achieve it?

Comment: `Please don't mark duplicate without giving proper solution!` that's not how it works, if it's a duplicate, it's because the duplicate has the answer already :p

Comment: Duplicate means that there does have been a solution. :(

Comment: @no1xsyzy well it does have a solution!

Comment: @ArnoldParge look at the sentence, `does have been` != `does have`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```js
var obj = {
  title: "This is title of item 1",
  desc: "This is description of 1",
  state: "inactive",
  toggleState: function() {
    console.log('title: ', this.title)
  }
}.toggleState();
```

Comment: Apologies for the previous comment. Didn't realised you changed from an arrow function to a regular one